# ASP.NET make number of lines editable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a number of lines of text on an .aspx page that I want a user to be able to edit, I am not storing this text/information anywhere in the database. I just want it to be information that is displayed to the user but can be editable, so the user can view the text and if there is a mistake or want to make a change they can do this by editing it.

I have seen that if you display data in a label and put a textbox beside it then, the textbox can move into the place of the label - I have done this for other text on the page however that method would not fit for this purpose because I require this edit of text to be for a number of lines.

Are there any suggestions to how this can be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just display it in another multi-line textbox by setting its TextMode property to multiline, and maybe styling it differently with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to do slick in-place editing use [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Comment: how would I go about beginning to add jquery to an aspx page? I have never done jquery before. Thanks

Comment: the best place to start is on the site - http://jquery.com/.  Basically you add a reference to the javascript files you need in the header of your page, and then write the code you want to execute in your own javascript block on the page.